# SQLite and Java charts and trend analysis without using ContentProvider

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, trend

I am trying to build an Android app with the SDK and use SQLite for database. The app will not be connected to a server (client only app with the logic and database in the client)

Would it still be possible to perform trend analysis and present charts and graphs on the data? As I am trying to look for the simplest solution possible due to time constraints, is it possible to use Java and SQLite for this without having to set up a contentprovider?

Thank you very much,

Cecilia

Comment: A `ContentProvider` is just a connection between the client and a data source(in many cases(as its interface already shows) a database). So what is the problem with using a normal `SQLiteDatabase` vs a `SQLiteDatabase` wrapped by a `ContentProvider`?

Comment: Thank you @Luksprog, I thought creating the ContentProvider would be a lengthy process though? That's why I was wondering whether there is a way to avoid that, am I totally off here?  (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html)

Comment: I don't see why would be a lengthy process. You'll need some boiler plate code beside the database code(if you know what you're doing and depending on the database structure this should be fast to make) but once you setup that it pretty straightforward. If time is a constraint and you don't have much knowledge about `ContentProviders` in general use a simple database. Remember that if your app requires sharing data with other applications a ContentProvider is the way to go.